# Orderby two fields with different value type Angularjs

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, sorting

I'm trying to order json data based on two fields, and the priority of ordering should be based on field value and then date.

Below is a test demo

Input json

```
[{
"title" : "Title 2",
"pin"   : false,
"date" : 20130411204207
},{
"title" : "Title 3",
"date" : 20140411204207
},{
"title" : "Title 4",
"date" : 20120411204207
},{
"title" : "Title 1",
"pin"   : true,
"date" :  20100411204207
}]
```

What i'm trying to do is  to make object with "pin : true" as first item and then rest of them should be based on descending order of "date", "pin" is an optional field. I was trying "orderBy" method, is there any workaround for this?

http://jsfiddle.net/tomalex0/tvLUK/1/

Output json

```
[
{
    "title": "Title 1",
    "pin": true,
    "date": 20100411204207
},
{
    "title": "Title 3",
    "date": 20140411204207
},
{
    "title": "Title 2",
    "pin": false,
    "date": 20130411204207
},
{
    "title": "Title 4",
    "date": 20120411204207
}
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get this working by converting the pin into a numeric value as below:

```
$filter('orderBy')($scope.sorted, ["0 + !!pin", "date"], true);
```

I have updated your fiddle with a [working version](http://jsfiddle.net/tvLUK/9/)

Answer (score 1):

Try using sort expression like this

```
 $scope.sortData = function (){
    var newdata = $filter('orderBy')(arrayval, ["pin == undefined ? -1 : (pin ? 1 : 0)","date"],true);
     console.log(newdata);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but still for the object with pin as false, its not considering the date for ordering.